# How to use CSS3 & HTML5 to simulate the minimize animation on Mac?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, css

I want to know how can I simulate the minimize animation on Mac using CSS3 & HTML5.

Comment: Do you mean the "Genie" Dock animation. I think it uses a skew animation.

Comment: See this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575919/genie-animation-javascript